# Do consistent-read scans in DynamoDB hide changes made after the scan starts?

Tags: amazon-dynamodb, dynamodb-queries

Given a `Scan` operation with `ConsistentRead=true` and a large resultset that spans many pages (such that follow-up requests are required to fetch subsequent pages): what happens if an item is updated **after the scan starts** but before the relevant page for that item is returned to us (when paginating through the scan results)?

When we eventually reach that page, will we see the updated item, or will we see the version of the item from when the scan started? Or is the behaviour unpredictable?

---

And: same question again, but for deletes?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consistent reads refers to consistency with respect to an individual item -- not the whole table.

When you initiate a scan it, with consistent reads, every item read will reflect it's up-to-date state at time of the request but that doesn't mean that the collection of items you get as a result of the scan represents a point in time snapshot when you initiated the scan. New items could be added while the scan is in progress and depending on where their key falls in the key-space they may or may not be included.

Same for deleted items.

You can also set up a simple test for this yourself by deliberately slowing down your scan and performing updates while you scan.